# display image in GWT

Tags: image, gwt, widget

I have created a widget to display the slideshow.In firefox,everything is fine but in chrome nothing happens. After I refresh with many times, the slideshow is displayed. I don't know Why. Can you give me some ideas? Tks
This is my GWT client:

```
public SlideClient() {
    super();
    setStyleName("flexslider");
    setHeight("100%");
    setWidth("100%");

}

@Override
public void updateFromUIDL(UIDL uidl, ApplicationConnection client) {
    this.client = client;
    this.paintableId = uidl.getId();
    listImage = Arrays.asList(uidl.getStringArrayAttribute("listImage"));
    listUrl = Arrays.asList(uidl.getStringArrayAttribute("listUrl"));

    loadImage();
    checkImagesLoadedTimer.run();
}

public void display() {
    m.setStyleName("slides");
    m.setHeight("100%");
    m.setWidth("100%");
    add(m);
}

public native void slideshow() /*-{
$wnd.$('.flexslider').flexslider({slideshowSpeed: 2000});
}-*/;

public native String getURL(String url)/*-{
return $wnd.open(url,
'target=_blank')
}-*/;

private Timer checkImagesLoadedTimer = new Timer() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (loadedImageElements.size() == toLoad) {
            display();
        } else {
            add(new Label("đang load "+loadedImageElements.size()));
            checkImagesLoadedTimer.schedule(2000);
        }
    }
};

private void loadImage() {
    for (String tmp : listImage) {
        AbsolutePanel panel = new AbsolutePanel();
        final Image ima = new Image(tmp);
        add(new Label("before put"));
        ima.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
                loadedImageElements.put(toLoad+"", ima);
                slideshow();
                add(new Label("đang put "+loadedImageElements.size()));
            }
        });
        add(new Label("after put"));

        panel.add(ima);
        m.add(panel);

        if (toLoad != 0) {
            panel.setVisible(false);
        }
        toLoad++;

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement an Image Loader to prepare your images before they are displayed? A clean solution would be to add the image elements to your page root as an invisible istance, wait for them to load and then use them elsewhere.

You should check out the tutorials about ImageBundling as well: [ImageResource](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle#ImageResource)

Here's a little extract from one of my image loader classes as you requested, altough there are different ways to realize that:

```
private HashMap<String,ImageElement> loadedImageElements = new HashMap<String,ImageElement>();
private int toLoad = 0;

private void loadImage(final String name, String url){
    final Image tempImage = new Image(url);             
    RootPanel.get().add(tempImage);

    ++toLoad;

    tempImage.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler(){
        public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {               
            loadedImageElements.put(name,ImageElement.as(tempImage.getElement()));
            tempImage.setVisible(false);                
        }           
    });
}
```

The image url is retrieved via a ClientBundle-Interface pointing towards the real positions of the images.
I also implemented a timer running in the background to check if all the images have been loaded:

```
private Timer checkImagesLoadedTimer = new Timer(){
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Loaded " + loadedImageElements.size() + "/" + toLoad + " Images.");
        if(loadedImageElements.size() == toLoad){
            buildWidget();
        }else{              
            checkImagesLoadedTimer.schedule(50);
        }
    }       
};
```

After everythign is ready, the original widget/page is created.

But as I said there are many ways to implement image loaders. Try out different implementations and select one that suits your needs best.

Comment: Tks. I will try it but can you give me some example about Image Loader?

Comment: I tried your way but nothings changed. I posted my widget client. Can you give me some ideal? Tks

Comment: Did you implement the timer? Your JS will throw a nullPointerException if you don't wait until the images are loaded. Also, you did not associate an unique name with the ImageElements, you used "" in your loader which will result in overwriting the association every time an image is loaded.

Comment: I fix the unique name of the ImageElements. I tried to implement the timer but i don't know what is the "buildWidget()" in your code....

Comment: buildWidget() is just some kidn of initialization Function for the element I was using. Its basically this way: onModuleLoad() => calls the timer, when ready => timer executes the "building" of the website. If you don't have tons of images and dont implement weird stuff, this procedure should not be noticeable by the user.

Comment: hix.I don't know why my loadedImageElements.size() is always 0. I have edit my code. Can you tell me why? Tks

Comment: Hello. It could be that there Is some kind of Exception thrown by cour code, maybe because you add the Image object ´ima´ to the loadedImageElements and not `ima.getElement()`. Do you use the GWT debugging mechanism? If not, you should change cour Code to use `System.pot.println()` or similar commands to output to the console while debugging and not adding new labels to the Website.